# How can I export mongoDB collection into .csv which is readable/compatible in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, csv, ssis, sql-server-2012

I used mongoexport to export the collection in to csv file along with fields. However when I tried to import the .csv in sql server using SSIS. I got errors and the data in preview section before executing the package was wrong. Can any one please guide me how can I export the data properly which can be easily imported into sql server. I am ready for minor tuning like adding id column or changing data types etc.

Comment: I have no experience with MongoDb, but I would like to know what is wrong about the csv file that it produced.  Can you give an example of what's wrong about the file and what errors you received?  Maybe there is something in the data (like commas) which is messing up the deliminter.  Does MongoExport all you to specify a text qualifier?

Comment: The problem is the structure of collection. It assigns one column based on first document in the collection however in the later document that column contains multiple sub columns which is creating the problem

Comment: Do you mean the data has hierarchical nesting or that these are two unrelated document structures and they do not line up properly?

Comment: Actually in tabular terms, I can say that one of the column has multiple columns

Comment: So how about parsing the file with a script task?

Comment: Yes but I am not very good at scripting :(

Comment: Please add a couple of sample lines to your question and we can post a sample on how to parse it.  At least something to get you started

Comment: {
  name: 'Kate Monster',
  ssn: '123-456-7890',
  addresses : [
     { street: '123 Sesame St', city: 'Anytown', cc: 'USA' },
     { street: '123 Avenue Q', city: 'New York', cc: 'USA' }
  ]
}

Comment: So this is a JSON format, if there a linefeed after each record like that?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are getting a json formatted object for each row in the file.  It may be different than that, and if that's the case, how you iterate through each might change a little.  But here is something to get you started:

1 - There is no out of the box JSON parser in .NET, but this seems to be a popular utility:  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json
2 - If you download the parser above, you'll have to go through a little pain to get it in a useable state with SSIS:

- Go to the source folder and open the solution for net40
- Sign the assembly
- comment out the lines that cause build errors 
  //[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Schema")] 
  //[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Newtonsoft.Json.Tests")]
- install the assembly to the gac

3 - Once all that is out of the way, add a file connection manager to your package and point it to the mongdb file
4 - Add a dataflow and then add a script component source to the dataflow
5 - In the script component, configure the connection manager that you created in step three, I gave mine the friendly name "MongoDbOutput"
6 - In the Inputs and Outputs section, go to Output0 and add a column for each field in the JSON object, setting datatypes to string as they will be int by default
7 - Open the script and add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json and System.IO
8 - The script below shows how to access the connection string to the file in the connection manager, read the file with a streamreader one line at a time and then parse each JSON object for each address.  One line is added for every address and the name and ssn are repeated for each line.

Note also, that I added a person and address class.  The json.net is pretty cool, it will take that json and push it into the object - provided all the fields match up.  Goog luck!

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{

    object MongoDbPath = Connections.MongoDbOutput.AcquireConnection(null);
    string filePath = MongoDbPath.ToString();

    using (StreamReader fileContents = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (fileContents.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            var contents = fileContents.ReadLine();
            Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(contents);
            foreach (address address in person.addresses)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.name = person.name;
                Output0Buffer.ssn = person.ssn;
                Output0Buffer.City = address.city;
                Output0Buffer.Street = address.street;
                Output0Buffer.country = address.cc;
            }   
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string ssn { get; set; }
    public address[] addresses 
        { get; set; }
}

public class address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string cc { get; set; }
}
```